# How to create a simple basic bar graph with a basic dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm just trying to create a basic data.frame as below:

```
data <- data.frame(Names = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), Marks = c(65, 78, 55, 66, 93))
```

And wanted to draw a simple bar graph out of it:

```
barplot(data)
```

But I keep getting the below error message:

> Error in barplot.default(data) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix

I tried looking for answers and also tried: `barplot(as.matrix(data))` but that gives a weird vertical graph.

What am I failing to see here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument `height` must contain *only the data*, that is, only the heights of the bars. To specify labels for the bars, you must pass the labels to the `names.arg` argument. (Alternatively, you could attach names to the `height` argument, but I think `names.arg` makes more sense in this case.) See [`barplot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html).

```
barplot(data$Marks,names.arg=data$Names);
barplot(setNames(data$Marks,data$Names)); ## alternative
```

[image: plot]

Comment: What you said made absolute sense. Thank you very much!